# Is there any sort of literature consisting of the description of paintings or images?

Tags: genre

I'd like to learn how to better write physical descriptions, in particular, of architectural features and interiors, but I'd like to develop this ability in general. Is there any genre of literature that focuses around describing paintings or pictures?

Comment: If you're looking for a *term* describing this kind of literature, please add the [terminology] tag. We don't do recommendations, however, so I have removed the second sub-question.

Comment: The literary term is [ekphrasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekphrasis).

Comment: [Cross-posted to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskLiteraryStudies/comments/11fpfga/is_there_any_sort_of_genre_of_literature/).